# Gradle project sync failed (Dependency error)

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

When add the new dependency the errors are shown as:

> C:\Users\Davud\Desktop\android projects\SaySistemleri\app\build.gradle
>       Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1.
>       Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1.
>       Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1.
>       Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1.
>       Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1.
>       Open File
> Show Details

Gradle Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.davud.numberrepresentator"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
}
```

Comment: download the latest playservices from your sdk manager , google it how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your top level build.gradle add this line of url maven.google.com

`allprojects { repositories { jcenter() maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } } }`

Comment: i faced this error after adding                                                                    Error:(2, 0) Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_5c9zbskam2ao5kybgkpe7no0k$_run_closure1$_closure4$_closure5@1e8a596e] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Davud\Desktop\android projects\SaySistemleri\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Can u please share the code where u added maven url?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
allprojects { repositories { jcenter() maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } } }


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.davud.numberrepresentator"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: Hey..u have to put in project level build.gradle ..not in this build.gradle

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
allprojects { repositories { jcenter() maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } } }


buildscript {

Comment: Error:(3, 0) Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_5c9zbskam2ao5kybgkpe7no0k$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure6@41b2922f] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Davud\Desktop\android projects\SaySistemleri\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Answer (score 0):

The potential problems are:
1. The dependency you added are having the same functions to the dependency you added before.
2. You might need to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
3. You might check your dependency repository( sometimes its from Maven)

`maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }`

[Check here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)